# Running an .exe application that references 2 files as arguments from within a c# console app

Tags: c#

I have an exe that runs just fine in command-line, but I need to be able to run it from within a c# application. To run the exe you must include a dicom file and a location for where a csv will be created. For example if I run it from the command-line it looks like this:

`PS D:\\home> .\DumpDicomTags.exe dicom report.csv`

DumpDicomTags.exe is the app that I need to run, dicom is the DICOM file that the app is reading from, and report.csv is giving the location and name of the output file.

I am attempting to run it this way in my c# console app

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace JunfengTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start(@"D:\Visual Studio Projects\JunfengTest\DumpDicomTags\DumpDicomTags.exe", "dicom report.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

This throws an error that the DICOM file failed to load. This means that it is properly accessing the DumpDicomTags.exe but it is not taking in the arguments correctly. If I try and escape the whitespace in the arguments like this

```
Process.Start(@"D:\Visual Studio Projects\JunfengTest\DumpDicomTags\DumpDicomTags.exe", "dicom /report.csv");
```

I get another error about an unknown option  `Unknown option: /report.csvDumpDicomTags version-1.0.0 Usage: DumpDicomTags InputDICOMFileName OutputCSVFileName` Which means again the the application is doing what it is suppose to, but the arguments are wrong. Can someone inform me how to properly structure my code so that it is the equivalent of the command-line input:

`PS D:\\home> .\DumpDicomTags.exe dicom report.csv`

Comment: In your script, the working directory D:\\home seems to be where both the .exe and the .csv are located.  Is this also true when running from Visual Studio?  Is there a "report.csv" in the "D:\Visual Studio Projects\JunfengTest\DumpDicomTags\" directory?  (Is DumpDicomTags.exe expecting to find report.csv at a path relative to itself? I would assume so, but we might as well check.)

Comment: the "report.csv" is created by the DumpDicomTag.exe, so it only exists in the directory once the applications has successfully ran. the "dicom" DICOM file is in the DumpDicomTags directory along side of the DumpDicomTags.exe

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by renaming my Visual Studio Projects directory to Visual_Studio_Projects. Then assigned the absolute paths to variables and everything works as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace JunfengTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            

            string arg1 = @"D:\Visual_Studio_Projects\JunfengTest\DumpDicomTags\dicom";
            string arg2 = @"D:\Visual_Studio_Projects\JunfengTest\DumpDicomTags\report.csv";

            string genArgs = arg1 + " " + arg2;
            string pathToFile = @"D:\Visual_Studio_Projects\JunfengTest\DumpDicomTags\DumpDicomTags.exe";

            Process.Start(pathToFile,genArgs);

        }
    }
}
```